# How to format a usb flash drive to Ext2?

Tags: debian, gnome, usb, ext2, gnome-disks

When I use a GUI environment, I have there only ext4, NTFS, FAT and other, but I need to type their name. I tried one time to type there `ext2`, but it seems it gets stuck. I was waiting a lot and it still did not format.
My OS Debian, using Gnome 3.

Comment: What are you using in `GUI`? Are you using `disks`?

Comment: @Debian_yadav Yes

Answer (score 2):

There are two steps. First you have to create the partition, then you have to build the filesystem on it. From the CLI as root, the following commands will format, and build a ext2 filesystem on a USB stick.

Stick the disk in. Run `dmesg` and note the new drive added.

As root:

```
fdisk /dev/sdX  # the drive letter only without a number

d (delete existing partitions.)
n (create new partition)
    use the default start and end blocks.
l (list the available partition types)
t (I think? I'm working from memory here)
    type the number "83" to set the partition to linux.
w  (writes the partition)
```

---

```
mkfs -t ext2 /dev/sdX1  # the drive letter and partition number of the flash disk
```

Pull the disk out, stick it back in and mount it the way your normally would.

Comment: Note that if the drive is already mounted, you will need to `umount` it first.

Answer (score 0):

You can [install if necessary and] use `gparted` to create an `ext2` file system in a partition.

```
sudo apt install gparted
```

`gparted`has a graphical user interface and is quite intuitive, I would say it is easier to use than Disks alias`gnome-disks`.

When you have selected the operations, please click on the tick icon   (create partitions, create file systems, add flags and labels ...).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the file system type manually.

Choose : Custom (Enter file system type) , under *Filesystem* type `ext2`